# Why haven't tracking tools like Hotjar and others worked on Vercel function + Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, serverless, vercel

I am a newbie and I am trying to add various trackers like Google Analytics, Hotjar, Matomo, and others to my Nuxt 3 project. However, they are not working. I deploy it to the Vercel serverless.

I want to know if serverless like Vercel and Netlify and if they cannot be used for tracking or analytics.